# ZendServer, Apache2 and VirtualHosts with SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have an ZendServer on a Ubuntu Linux. The ZendServer uses Apache2, so that's where I'm looking for a proper configuration to setup a set of Virtualhosts with SSL.

I am not longer using `httpd.conf` as it was blank, and I'm assuming no longer in use?

As such I have been modifying `../sites-enabled/default` and  `../sites-enabled/default-ssl`

Here is what I have (and the SSL host is not being found despite the server starting normally.

If I remove the references to '`IfModule mod_ssl.c`' I get an SSL error that the certificate is so long.

Couple of questions:

1. What am I doing wrong with the NameVirtualHost configuation
2. If I want to specify individual IP addresses for each site for SSL this configuration doesn't work - so where do I reference those IP addresses?
3. SSL Certificate file: I downloaded the **.PEM** file from Parallels, so it should contain the certificate key, so I will change that reference to a single: `SSLCertificateFile`

**Update: How I got it working**

> Since I was working with a basically unconfigured version of ZendServer 5.5 + Apache2, I think I was very confused about the basic vhosts setting, thanks to you guys for putting me on the right track to using SH commands to get things working.

1. Since I was using *ZendServer 5.5.0 + Apache2* I think the configuration was a bit different than most people were used too, I followed the instructions [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412) very carefully.
2. Once I was able to create the configuration files in the correct place, I was able to use commands: `$ a2ensite my_site_config_filename` & `$ a2dissite my_site_config_filename` to enable and disable the sites before restarting zend-server.
3. Keep in mind that if I made changes to the configuration files for the individual sites at `/apache2/sites-avaliable`, I would disable and re-enable using the previously mentioned commands (seemed necessary to get apache2 to rebuild the symlinks or some such ... not sure if this is necessary but it made sense)

> I also ran `a2dissite default` & `a2dissite default-ssl` as they seemd to be conflicting with my newly created configuration.

4. SSL: I placed the configuration for SSL in the same configuration file as the the port 80 file as follows (I'm using my own cert, but in this code I just point to the 'snake-oil-cert' from apache!).

> **And of course** run: `$ a2enmod ssl` *(per cjc's original answer!)*

**/apache2/sites-avaliable/mysite**

```
#
#  mysitename.com (/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.mysitename.com)
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName  mysitename.com
        ServerAlias mysitename.com

        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mysitename.com/htdocs/

        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/www.mysitename.com/cgi-bin/
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>

        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog  /var/www/www.mysitename.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/www.mysitename.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName  maryshop.com
    ServerAlias maryshop.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mysitename.com/htdocs/

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convinience.
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

    #   Certificate Authority (CA):
    #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
    #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
    #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
    #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

    #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
    #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
    #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
    #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
    #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

    #   Client Authentication (Type):
    #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
    #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
    #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
    #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
    #SSLVerifyClient require
    #SSLVerifyDepth  10

    #   Access Control:
    #   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
    #   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
    #   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
    #   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
    #   for more details.
    #<Location />
    #SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
    #            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
    #            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
    #           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
    #</Location>

    #   SSL Engine Options:
    #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
    #   o FakeBasicAuth:
    #     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
    #     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
    #     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
    #     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
    #     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
    #   o ExportCertData:
    #     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
    #     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
    #     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
    #     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
    #     into CGI scripts.
    #   o StdEnvVars:
    #     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
    #     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
    #     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
    #     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
    #     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
    #   o StrictRequire:
    #     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
    #     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
    #     and no other module can change it.
    #   o OptRenegotiate:
    #     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
    #     directives are used in per-directory context.
    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
    #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
    #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
    #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
    #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
    #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
    #     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
    #     SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
    #     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
    #     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
    #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
    #     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
    #     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
    #     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
    #     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
    #     works correctly.
    #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
    #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
    #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
    #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
    #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
    #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**/apache2/conf.d/virtual.conf**

```
#
#  We're running multiple virtual hosts.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

**/apache2/conf.d/virtual-ssl.conf**

```
#
#  We're running multiple virtual hosts.
#
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

Comment: "If I remove the references to '`IfModule mod_ssl.c`' I get an SSL error that the certificate is so long." - can you provide the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: Yes, I get this:
`SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)`

Comment: Sorry @Shane Madden wanted to mention it back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable the SSL module using "a2enmod"?  This is analogous to the sites-available/sites-enabled thing, where symlinks are created from mods-enabled to the files in mods-available.

To use the IP address, you will put it in the VirtualHost line, something like `<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>.`

Comment: No I did not -- should I be looking into that?

Comment: Yes, if your SSL module isn't enabled, all that conditional logic in the conf file tells Apache not to start up the SSL server.

Comment: Sorry, the code snippet I had earlier wasn't sanitized properly.  For SSL, it'll be port 443, not 80, but, generally, yes.  You will need separate VirtualHosts with their own IP address for each SSL server you're setting up.

Comment: I'm going to change the code I put up to reflect those changes -- but it still doesn't help and regular `http` requests start to file when I do that -- hence the current `*:80` config (wanted to get SSL working first before adding multiple hosts)

Comment: ok ran the following: `$ a2enmod ssl` and restarted --

Comment: Yeah, don't worry about the conf for now.  Get the ssl module enabled.  Verify that the mods-enabled directory now has symlinks to ssl files in mods-available.

Comment: Also ran $a2enmod vhost_alias (since I figured it was necessary) -- still no joy, using the static address as you suggested I get neither `http` or `https` when I use `*:80` & `*:443` I get `http` but on `https` _SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)_

Comment: I now have symlinks for `ssl.conf` & `ssl.load` in `mods-enabled`

Comment: Did you look at this? https://support.servertastic.com/entries/323560-error-code-ssl-error-rx-record-too-long

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1308/discussion-between-cjc-and-jordan-baucke)

Comment: I gave cjc the answer as he was very helpful! I am going to write a brief exp. of what I did to get it working in my original post (-8